# cmd keeps telling me error cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I've been trying now for a couple days to run this but it hasn't gone through for some reason. This is the code:**strong text**

```
public class namegenerator {
    public static void main(string[] args) {

    string[] firstnames = {"James", "Philip", "Danny", "Bob", "joshua"};

    string[] lastnames = {"Franklin", "Hunter", "Johnson", "Smith", "Jones"};

    int onelength = firstnames.length;
    int twolength = lastnames.length;

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * onelength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twolength);

    String phrase = firstname [rand1] + " " + lastname [rand2];

    System.out.println("Your fake name is, " + phrase);

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no such keyword as `string` in Java... You mean `String`

Answer (score 2):

You had two mistakes.

String is with "S", not "s"

And in your `String phrase=` you did not add "s" to "firstname"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] firstnames = {"James", "Philip", "Danny", "Bob", "joshua"};

    String[] lastnames = {"Franklin", "Hunter", "Johnson", "Smith", "Jones"};

    int onelength = firstnames.length;
    int twolength = lastnames.length;

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * onelength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twolength);

    String phrase = firstnames[rand1] + " " + lastnames[rand2];

    System.out.println("Your fake name is, " + phrase);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your main method declaration, the class name is **String** and not string

```
 public static void main(String args[])
```